# Which installation type should I choose to install 14.04 on an USB flash drive where I previously had 16.04?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I had Ubuntu 16.04 bootable on my USB. I'm using Windows 10 and I haven't used Ubuntu as a partition but only as a USB pnp. Now I want to use 14.04 version instead. So I formatted the USB completely and again made it bootable for 14.04. Then I partitioned it on my Windows 10 and started installing this version (14.04). But, at the "Installation Type" dialog, I am confused as to which option I should choose from these 3 options:

1. Erase Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and reinstall
2. Erase the disk and install Ubuntu
3. Something else

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry if my previous answer was confusing.

If you select the first option, it will erase the ubuntu installed in the usb stick and install ubuntu 14.04 while keeping your media/document files.

The second option will erase the entire disk and you will loose everything stored in the usb.

If you select the 3rd option, you will be able to partition the drive and select where to install what. If you do that, make sure to select the USB drive to install the bootloader.

Comment: OP is not even installing on a hard drive... Your answer is very vague. Why would OP want to partition the USB in this situation?